# How to add class in AngularJS on ng-click for multiple elements (smartly)?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have 2 "lists" (in HTML). I want to make it so that any option I click, adds a class that changes the `background-color` of the `li` element to red. If any individual option is clicked again, then it removes the class (so the background reverts to white):

This is what the list looks like in my current HTML page/template:

**List A**

```
<ul>
    <li>Something 1</li>
    <li>Something 2</li>
</ul>
```

**List B**

```
<ul>
    <li>Otherthing A</li>
    <li>Otherthing B</li>
    <li>Otherthing C</li>
</ul>
```

My current state is having each `li` have it's own expression, with its own individual `$scope` variable that keeps track of true or false. (Individual `$scope` variable meaning. `$scope.otherthingaclicked = true`, `$scope.otherthingbclicked = true`, `$scope.otherthingcclicked=false`, etc.)

```
<li ng-class="expression">Otherthing A</li>
```

There has got to be a better way. How can I make this smarter?

Comment: `with its own individual "$scope" variable ` Those value are different from each other? In other words, could be a situation that one `li` will has one class and another will has a different class?

Comment: Individual $scope variable meaning. $scope.otherthingaclicked = true, $scope.otherthingbclicked = true, $scope.otherthingcclicked=false, etc.

Comment: can you please fiddle it out.

Comment: I don't understand.. If you need to change the background for each `li` individual - so you have to "store" a switches to each of them.. It's logical make sense,

Comment: Given the fact I have two groupings, is there an easy way to "store" switches for them and reference in template without having to create individual $scope.XXX variables for each of the 5 options? It just seems like poor code to me...

Comment: `ngClick` exposes an `$event` variable that you can feed to a function. Angular also a `this` on every element on a page, which is a reference to the element. Angular elements expose method `.toggleClass()`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, there is a better solution to it. Here comes the usage of the Angular directives:

```
myApp.directive("toggleClass", function() {
    return {
        link: function($scope, element, attr) {
            element.on("click", function() {
                element.toggleClass("option-selected");
            });
        }
    }
});
```

Then, apply it to your `li`s:

```
<ul>
    <li toggle-class>Something 1</li>
    <li toggle-class>Something 2</li>
</ul>
```

And, your CSS:

```
li.option-selected {
    background: red;
}
```

```js
var myApp = angular.module("sa", []);

myApp.directive("toggleClass", function() {
  return {
    link: function($scope, element, attr) {
      element.on("click", function() {
        element.toggleClass("option-selected");
      });
    }
  }
});
```

```css
li.option-selected {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<ul ng-app="sa">
  <li toggle-class>Something 1</li>
  <li toggle-class>Something 2</li>
  <li toggle-class>Something 3</li>
  <li toggle-class>Something 4</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

Are you going to use (or save) the result of what `li` items the user has clicked? If you do so, you might need to save a boolean value for each `li` element.

```
//JS
$scope.listA = [
    { label: "Something 1", checked: false },
    { label: "Something 2", checked: false },
    { label: "Something 3", checked: false }
];
```

Then you use a `ng-repeat` and `ng-click` to handle it.

```
<!-- HTML -->
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="item in listA" ng-class="{ 'selected': item.checked }">
        <a href="javascript://" 
            ng-click="item.checked = !item.checked">{{item.label}}</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```